# How to have same markup is same in ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate in a Repeater - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asp.net-4.0

I have a rather complex markup in the `ItemTemplate` of a `asp:Repeater` and the markup is same for the `AlternatingItemTemplate` as well. I'd like to not duplicate the markup. Is this possible with a Repeater?

The list I am building doesn't support sorting/editing/adding and is essentially a list of items. Since I am using ASP.NET 4.0, do you suggest an alternate control for the `asp:Repeater` (Again, I'd like to not duplicate markup in the control you suggest)

Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason then to have the `AlternatingItemTemplate` and not skip it completely? This way you could have only one template, the `ItemTemplate` displayed in the same way for odd/even items. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Ah - I didn't realize the `AlternatingItemTemplate` is optional. Maybe you should add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the reason then to have the AlternatingItemTemplate and not skip it completely? This way you could have only one template, the ItemTemplate displayed in the same way for odd/even items. Is there any difference between them?

Also remember that simple differences between odd/even rows (like a different css style)  can be implemented on the `ItemTemplate` by utilizing the `Container.DataItemIndex` (e.g. `CssStyle='<# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "ItemStyle" : "AlternatingItemStyle"' #>`

Comment: Or you could move that work completely to CSS, further simplifying the repeater: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know that :) Seems that it doesn't work in IE though.

Comment: Hmm, might be a version thing, wasn't supported in IE7/8 so it can be risky to use in production sites unless you want to annoy your older IE users into upgrading :) Compatibility info is here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#CSS3 (down about a page from that spot). There's also a good article somewhere on A List Apart with a JS method that will work with even more browsers

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

1. Create a user control with the markup you desire and add a Boolean property `AltRow` that will determine how to display the row.
2. Use javascript/jquery/CSS to implement alternate row stylization and ignore the AlternatingItemTemplate altogether.

Answer (score 1):

In-line Page code for the TR :

```
<tr class="<%# (Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0) ? "AltRowStyle" : "" %>">
```

CSS Code for a table with a class of 'caseTable'

```
.caseTable tr.AltRowStyle  td 
{
    background-color: #FAF8DC;
}
```